# Get Webcam stream using Aforge.NET in C# and WPF

Tags: .net, multithreading, silverlight, asynchronous, aforge

I want to capture a webcam feed using my camera. For that I am using the 2 references: `AForge.Video.dll` and `AForge.Video.DirectShow.dll`.

[Here's](http://irslab.blogspot.com/2010/07/webcam-using-aforgenet-part-ii.html) a snippet I found:

```cs
public FilterInfoCollection CamsCollection;
public VideoCaptureDevice Cam = null;

void Cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{   
  frameholder.Source = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(); 
  /* ^
   * Here it cannot convert implicitly from System.Drawing.Bitmap to
   * System.Windows.Media.ImageSource
   */

}

private void startcam_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  CamsCollection = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

  Cam = new VideoCaptureDevice(CamsCollection[1].MonikerString);
  Cam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(Cam_NewFrame);
  Cam.Start();
}

private void stopcam_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Cam.Stop();
}
```

}

They use a `PictureBox` to display the frames. As I am working in WPF, I used [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/833ca60f-6a11-4836-bb2b-ef779dfe3ff0/)

To sum up here's what my code looks like currently.

```
public FilterInfoCollection CamsCollection;
public VideoCaptureDevice Cam = null;


void Cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{

    System.Drawing.Image imgforms = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();


    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit ();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream ();

    imgforms.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    bi.StreamSource  = ms;
    frameholder.Source = bi; 
   /* ^ runtime error here because `bi` is occupied by another thread.
    */
    bi.EndInit();
}

private void startcam_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    CamsCollection = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

    Cam = new VideoCaptureDevice(CamsCollection[1].MonikerString);
    Cam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(Cam_NewFrame);
    Cam.Start();
}

private void stopcam_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Cam.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit1:** for a detailed explanation view my [blogpost](http://seaflection.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/getting-image-stream-using-webcam-in-wpf-asynchronous-ui-updating/) on the same topic.

---

I fixed the error using the `Dispatcher` class as a mutex:

```
void Cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        System.Drawing.Image imgforms = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(); 

        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(); 
        bi.BeginInit(); 

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
        imgforms.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp); 
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 

        bi.StreamSource = ms; 
        bi.EndInit();

        //Using the freeze function to avoid cross thread operations 
        bi.Freeze();

        //Calling the UI thread using the Dispatcher to update the 'Image' WPF control         
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            frameholder.Source = bi; /*frameholder is the name of the 'Image' WPF control*/
        }));     

    }
```

Now it runs as expected and I get good performance without any drop in the fps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support Silverlight, be it for web or standalone or WP7, you shouldn't start with WPF, as many features from WPF are lacking in Silverlight.

Here is a Silverlight 4+ tutorial:

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Capturing-the-Webcam-in-Silverlight-4.aspx

Comment: hey. Thanks... As of now I will be requiring lots of image processing for the application that I am working on. So I am using Aforge for the same(i.e for capturing the video and all)