# Barcode using UWP C# windows 8.1

Tags: c#, uwp, barcode, zxing

Please, how can I scan barcode using webcam of my PC? I used ZXing Nugget and could only generate (write) QR Code but not read. 
These are my C# code

XAML

```
    <Page
        x:Class="Bembem_Samples.FrontScan"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:Bembem_Samples"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

        <Grid Background ="CadetBlue">
            <StackPanel
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Button x:Name="testZxing" Click="testZxing_Click"/>
                <TextBlock
                    FontSize="18"
                    x:Name="txtStatus"/>
                <TextBlock
                    FontSize="18"
                    x:Name="txtResult"
                    Margin="0,4,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Page>
```

C# Code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
    using Windows.Foundation;
    using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
    using Windows.Media;
    using Windows.Media.Capture;
    using Windows.Storage;
    using Windows.Storage.Streams;
    using Windows.UI.Popups;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
    using ZXing;

    // The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

    namespace tinoTestField
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        public sealed partial class CamElement : Page
        {
            public FrontScan()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();

            }
            private void testZxing_Click(){
                IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
                // load a bitmap - *Bitmap* is not recognised by the library
                var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.LoadFrom("C:\\sample-barcode-image.png");
                // detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
                var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
                // do something with the result
                if (result != null)
                {
                  txtDecoderType.Text = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
                  txtDecoderContent.Text = result.Text;
                }
          }
       }
    }
```

Please, how can I scan barcode using webcam of my PC? I used ZXing Nugget and could only generate (write) QR Code but not read.

Also if anyone knows how I can resolve this or suggestion on how to open webcam using captureElement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really expect us to write the program for you? Do it yourself

Comment: Hi @musefan, am only asking for directions. Doing it myself will certainly make me learn better. 

Do you know any resources?

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you have here is single image reader, if you want to read from webcam you have to write a lil code for that.

**Steps to follow**

1. Get Library which can stream webcam data (like [Aforge](http://www.aforgenet.com/)) [Aforge Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138423/get-webcam-stream-using-aforge-net-in-c-sharp-and-wpf)
2. grab an image from that stream.
3. process that image to find the barcode
4. Repeat

**Note:** This just an overview that how can you do that there is a lot of things you have to consider while building barcode reader.

**Update:-**

While researching on this I found [Github Repo](https://github.com/eissa4444/use-a-camera-as-a-barcode-scanner) this is not complete solution but will give a good leap in what you want to achieve

Comment: Okay, @Mihir Dave. I will read the article and revert my findings. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Mihir Dave. Takes for your effort. I really appreciate. 

My basic issue is to view an image on UWP (desktop) without launching the camera. I have read and still very confused. I used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CaptureElement and it's did not work and so did many other I read. Creating Barcode works.

Comment: so you are facing issue in accessing webcam? and what do you mean by "without launching the camera" ?

Comment: Normally, I launch Camera on my PC, Capture image as a bitmap and save (as base64 string). I want to see the image on the app before clicking a button to capture.

Comment: so basically you need to see live webcam stream in your app right?

Comment: @Tino Not to clear what you are doing to use the webcam and it should be another issue. Please clarify the issue on a new thead with more details about it so that we can help you in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: so Tino as BreezeLiu-MSFT Liu mentioned you can open a new thread where you can put your new question and waht you tried so far. regarding live stream webcam access Aforge is the answer. i have personally used it and it's awesome so post a new question if you're facing some issue with that

Comment: Mihir Dave and @BreezeLiu-MSFT Liu. 
Thank you very much. I can use CaptureElement now. I did enable it on package.appmanifest. Remain to decode Qr-Codes.

Thank you again.

Comment: Great... @Tino.